# Unable to understand this Angular method

Tags: angular

I saw a piece of code in Angular and i am unable to understand it.

```
remove_stock({group, index}: {group: FormGroup, index: number}) {
    const control = this.form.get('stock') as FormArray;
    control.removeAt(index);
}
```

I understand there is a method called remove_stock and since it uses an parenthesis it takes an argument.

But I am not sure about this argument .
I know in typescript that anything enclosed in braces is an object and whatever is preceding a colon is the name of the type.

But what i don't get is this

```
{group, index}: {group: FormGroup, index: number}
```

Can someone please explain

I have taken this from a screenshot of the course from ultimate Angular and i am stumped.
Here is the link to that image

```
https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/680140010.webp?mw=1500&amp;mh=844&amp;q=70
```

Thanks

Comment: Yeah it takes group and index as parameters-- group is of type FormGroup and index is of type number

Comment: how you have this written isnt actually valid typescript. This wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this syntax have nothing to do with typescript, it's a es6 syntax.
It's called Destructuring assignment, Take a look at this link [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
Take a look at this code:

```
const user = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'user' 
};

const {id, name} = user;
```

These lines of code identical as this

```
const user = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'user' 
};

const id = user.id;
const name = user.name;
```

And your function above, that will be like this

```
remove_stock(input: {group: FormGroup, index: number}) {
  const index = input.index;
  const group = input.group;
  const control = this.form.get('stock') as FormArray;
  control.removeAt(index);
}
```

Comment: it is es6 not es5

Comment: why not make the method call like this removeStock ({group: FormGroup, index: number}) isn't it simpler ? instead of remove_stock(input: {group: FormGroup, index: number})

Comment: `remove_stock(input: {group: FormGroup, index: number})` is typescript syntax. The right hand is the type, left hand is the variable name. And the example above split the `input` by `destruction syntax` into 2 variables {group, index}

Comment: Lupa wow thanks for that explanation I get it now.I am familiar with Object destructing but was still stumped by that.Thanks a ton for making this crystal clear

Answer (score 1):

that's a function that removes an element from an array
according to the example that I found in this link https://www.cnblogs.com/Answer1215/p/6592580.html
a formgroup is created by means of an array

```
removeStock ({group, index}: {group: FormGroup, index: number}) {
     const control = this.form.get ('stock') as FormArray;
     control.removeAt (index);
   }
```

two parameters are passed which are the class and the identifier

```
{group, index}
```

here the data type of the parameters is expressed

```
{group: FormGroup, index: number}
```

a constant is declared that contains the total of the elements
const control = this.form.get ('stock') as FormArray;

it removes the element identified by index

```
control.removeAt (index);
```

XD That's all I speak Spanish so excuse my writing done on google XD

Comment: You conveyed the message across :) Your english is good enough for me to visit spain and have a convo :).My question though why not make the method call like this removeStock ({group: FormGroup, index: number}) isn't it simpler ? What am i missing here